# Redstone loop not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

After building and exploring in Minecraft, I chose [this sticky piston mob grinder](http://www.kevblog.co.uk/how-to-build-a-minecraft-piston-mob-grinder/) to learn about redstone - which may have been a bit too ambitious, as I'm having problems with the loop which sends pulses to the sticky pistons.

I have set it up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUpaE.jpg), and the circuit lights up when I step on the plate, and stays on constantly when I step off, until I break it by removing some redstone.

What I think should be happening when I step on the plate is that the circuit should activate, sending current round the loop, each time round sending a pulse out to the sticky pistons (which I'm fairly sure are wired up correctly, as they do move when they receive current) - and that this should continue, even when I step off the plate.

I've been fiddling around with this for 2 days, and just *cannot* figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you stand on the pressure plate for a while? I think you're just supposed to run across it, so you get a pulse going around the circuit but don't saturate the entire thing.

Comment: Buttons are far better to start these types of clocks. Their duration is predictable and it's a lot harder to saturate the loop (you'd need to push the button repeatedly for quite some time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop is called a "clock" -- searching for that might help. My guess would be try increasing the delay in repeater time and don't stand on the plate for very long. What you want is for part of the loop to be lit up so that moves through the repeaters and back around again. If it still doesn't work, try a different clock -- they're basically interchangeable.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, both. I must have been standing on the plate for too long - just tried running across it and now it's working perfectly - amazing!